# i am beginner in programming so trying to write program to "converting numbers in words in python" could you check my below code?

Tags: python

```
num=int(input('enter one number'))

units= 
{1:'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four',5:'five',6:'six',7:'seven',8:'eight',9:'nine',10:'ten',0:'zero',
11:'eleven',12:'tweleve',13:'thirteen',14:'fourteen',15:'fifteen',16:'sixteen',17:'seventeen',18:'eighteen',19:'nineteen'}

tens={2:'twenty',3:'thirty',4:'fourty',5:'fifty',6:'sixty',7:'seventy',8:'eighty',9:'ninety'}

hundreds={1:'one hundred',2:'two hundred',3:'three hundred',4:'four hundred',5:'five hundred',6:'six hundred',7:'seven hundred',8:'eight hundred',9:'nine hundred'}

unitdigit=num%10

tenthdigit=num//10

hundredthdigit=num//100

output=(hundreds[hundredthdigit]+' '+tens[tenthdigit]+' '+units[unitdigit])

print(output)
```

Comment: Without specifying if there is something wrong with your code, what you intend for it to do, what your problem is, etc, it is impossible to know what you need and how to help you here. Please add the necessary details to your question. Is something wrong with this code, or are you just trying to get a review of it?

Comment: i am getting error please assist me

Comment: The haggis library (my creation) has a function for doing this quite comprehensively: [`haggis.numbers.english`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#haggis.numbers.english).

Comment: "_i am getting error please assist me_" what error? Without specifying what error, I have no clue what you are trying to do and what is happening.

Comment: What are your expected inputs? For example, if you allow numbers less than 100 as input (5, 30 etc.), your `hundredthdigit` and/or `tenthdigit` would be 0 and that would throw a KeyError as there is no value for those in the corresponding dictionaries. This [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-number-to-words/) might be a good reference for you.

Comment: I suggest using debugging/print statements to check your values of the variables you have (like `tenthdigit`). Try it for different inputs - there is a logical error there which is why you get an error. 
For example, for an input like `125`, what is your program doing v/s what it should be doing. Then go ahead and try figuring out how to fix it. 
As a beginner I believe this is the kind of exercise that will help you, not someone just giving you the right code. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including the full error message along with input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to convert to an integer. You could just get the index of the number, convert it to an integer and get the value:

```
num=input('enter one number')
units={1:'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four',5:'five',6:'six',7:'seven',8:'eight',9:'nine',10:'ten',0:'zero',
11:'eleven',12:'tweleve',13:'thirteen',14:'fourteen',15:'fifteen',16:'sixteen',17:'seventeen',18:'eighteen',19:'nineteen'}

tens={2:'twenty',3:'thirty',4:'fourty',5:'fifty',6:'sixty',7:'seventy',8:'eighty',9:'ninety'}

hundreds={1:'one hundred',2:'two hundred',3:'three hundred',4:'four hundred',5:'five hundred',6:'six hundred',7:'seven hundred',8:'eight hundred',9:'nine hundred'}
unitdigit=num[2]
tenthdigit=num[1]
hundredthdigit=num[0]
output=(hundreds.get(int(hundredthdigit))+' '+tens.get(int(tenthdigit))+' '+units.get(int(unitdigit)))

print(output)
```

Comment: Or, to improve it in cases where there aren't three digits, use negative indexing, i.e. `unitdigit=num[-1]` for the **last** digit, not the **third**.

Comment: 1. numbers lower than `100` will raise `IndexError` at `unitdigit`, lower than `10` will raise same error at `tenthdigit`, 2. this logic will not work for `10`-`19` numbers, 3. no correct handle for `zero`.

Answer (score 0):

still not perfect but I tried to do minimum corrections

```py
num=int(input('enter one number'))

units= {1:'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four',5:'five',6:'six',7:'seven',8:'eight',9:'nine',10:'ten',0:'zero',11:'eleven',12:'tweleve',13:'thirteen',14:'fourteen',15:'fifteen',16:'sixteen',17:'seventeen',18:'eighteen',19:'nineteen'}

tens={2:'twenty',3:'thirty',4:'fourty',5:'fifty',6:'sixty',7:'seventy',8:'eighty',9:'ninety'}

hundreds={1:'one hundred',2:'two hundred',3:'three hundred',4:'four hundred',5:'five hundred',6:'six hundred',7:'seven hundred',8:'eight hundred',9:'nine hundred'}

if num > 19:
  unitdigit=num%10
  if num < 100:
    tenthdigit=num//10
  else:
    tenthdigit=(num-100*(num//100))//10
else:
  unitdigit=num
  tenthdigit=-1

hundredthdigit=num//100

output=(hundreds.get(hundredthdigit, '')+' '+tens.get(tenthdigit, '')+' '+(units.get(unitdigit, '') if units.get(unitdigit, '') != 'zero' or (units.get(unitdigit, '') == 'zero' and tens.get(tenthdigit, '') == '' and hundreds.get(hundredthdigit, '') == '') else '') )

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error on `units=` which either needs to have the assigned dictionary on that line or you need to escape the linebreak with a backslash.

`units= {`...

or

`units= \`

As for the KeyError, you need to rethink your algorithm. `unitdigit` can never be more than 9 because you limiting it with the modulus operator.

You also need to handle for cases when tens and hundreds are zero.